# Duplicating "Content: Title" field in Views and modifying them separately in hook_views_pre_render

Tags: 7, views

I'm creating a View (Views 3.x) which has the "Content: Title" ($node->title) field entered in the fields **twice** (+ more fields). Let's call them `title` and `title_1`.

`title` is set to "Exclude from display" and is being used as a replacement token on a different views field.

`title_1` is set to display as normal.

I'm trying to use [`hook_views_pre_render`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7) to make `title` all lowercase, and replace the spaces with dashes (basically turning it into a url-friendly format). But when I inspect the `results` array of the view, I only get a single value for the node title. And modifying that single value changes both `title` and `title_1` instances

[image: screenshot of views result]

I could add a "dummy" field into my view, and dump the converted title in there, and use that dummy field in the rewrite, but that feels so dirty.

Is there a good way to manipulate duplicated node titles without having to resort to such techniques? Maybe I'm using a wrong hook, or maybe I should look into doing it through views field templates?

Comment: A views_hook_post_render is not easy to work with, but would separate the different uses of the title so they don't contaminate.  The evil [views_php](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php) would let you use the [title] token inside some php cleaning functions for your processing.  Consider it a necessary evil.

Comment: [`hook_preprocess_views_view_fields`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view_fields/7) would be the best place IMO